# C++ compare values with unlimited input

Tags: c++, numbers, int, compare, min

It is an assignment. I was requested to write a program which compare the value of unlimited number of inputs. The input ends with 0. And i have to show the number of the minimum number counted. Below is my current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num,minct=0,temp=0;
    int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    cout<<"Enter numbers:";
    do{
        cin>>num;
        if (num<=min &&num!=0){
            min=num;
            minct++;
        }

    }
    while(num!=0);

    cout<<"The smallest number is " << min<<" ."<<endl;
    cout<<"The occurrence count of the smallest number is "<<minct<<" ."<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In this code, the number counted is always larger than the actual value by 1 when the minimum number is not in the first of the input. How can i make it to be accurate?

Comment: Simply working through your algorithm on paper would have revealed the problem.

Comment: ..or a trivial debugging effort.

Comment: I am asking for the problems on my algorithm. I had been working for two days before that.  Two days on 16 LOC.  Right.

Comment: I mean before i coming to this website to ask for the error in my algorithm

Answer (score 0):

```
if(num<=min && num!=0){
    if(num<min) {
        min=num;
        minct=1;
    }
    else if(num==min) {
        minct++;
    }
}
```